# Getting a Map from Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a map (and some other vars), but the map is returning a **null**

Here's how it looks in Firestore's:
[image]

And here's my code:

```
Future<void> getUserData() async {
    final userDocs =
        await Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('uid', isEqualTo: User.uid).getDocuments();

    for (var doc in userDocs.documents) {
      User.name = doc.data['name'];
      User.email = doc.data['email'];
      User.swipedUidsMap = doc['swipedUsers']; <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
      print(User.swipedUidsMap);
    }
  }
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Here's the definition of that Map:

```
static Map<String, bool> swipedMatchingUidsMap = {};
```

Comment: Is swipedUsers empty like in the picture?

Comment: Yes, it is @Henok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to get the data from the document on the line you marked.
It should be:
`User.swipedUidsMap = doc.data['swipedUsers'];`

Cheers!